# How to put the Tableau dashboard into a google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, tableau-api, google-forms

I want to put a map published to Tableau public in a Google form. I'm not sure how to do this because currently, images or videos are only put in the Google forms. I tried to solve this using the google apps script, but I don't know how to put "iframe" into the google apps script. Is there anyone who can tell me how to put a map made in Tableau into a Google form?

Comment: The iframe is an html tag name.  So it must go into an html page. [ref](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP)

Comment: If you can't insert it via the UI then you cant embed it using Apps Script either. If your map isn't an image file, I suggest filing a feature request for the addition of adding maps to Forms using the `? > Send feedback` menu item in the bottom-right hand corner of a new form page.